# how to remove chat in ejabber using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ejabberd, xmpp4r

I know how to send but i don't know how to recive and delete it.

```
    jid = Jabber::JID.new('user')
    client = Jabber::Client.new(jid)
    client.connect('54.187.67.96',5222)
    client.auth('password')
    client.send(Jabber::Presence.new.set_show(:chat).set_status('Rails!'))


    # Send an Instant Message.
    body = 'Hello from Rails'
    to_jid = Jabber::JID.new('user')
    message = Jabber::Message::new(to_jid, body).set_type(:normal).set_id('1')
    client.send(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

See [`stream.rb`](https://github.com/xmpp4r/xmpp4r/blob/master/lib/xmpp4r/stream.rb) for the code you're running. [`add_message_callback`](https://github.com/xmpp4r/xmpp4r/blob/master/lib/xmpp4r/stream.rb#L480-L490) looks like the winner to me. Deleting a message is not core Jabber so you need to talk it over with the server.